# Interface as method parameter type works but not List of Interface

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface and 2 classes inheriting that interface like below

```
public interface ILeader
{
    int ID { set; get; }
    string Name { set; get; }
}
public class User : ILeader
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
public class Group : ILeader
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

Now i have 2 method which has a parameter of type `ILeader` and IList of ILeader

```
public void Change(ILeader leader)
{
  //do some thing           
}
public void ChangeList(IList<ILeader> leaderList)
{
  //do some thing           
}
```

now i can pass an object of either `Group` or `User` to Change method and it works. But when i try to do the same with a `List` to `ChangeList` method it gives me compile time error.

```
IList<User> userList=new List<User>();
userList.Add(new User { ID=1, Name ="Happy"});

Change(userList[0]);  //this works

ChangeList(userList);  //this throws compile error
```

The error is

```
cannot convert from List<User> to List<ILeader>
```

How to make my `ChangeList` method work so that i can pass both a list of `Users` and `Groups` ?

Comment: You may not be able to, depending on what you're wanting to do with `ChangeList`.  What does `ChangeList` do?

Comment: @DStanley: Do some filteration on the list items and reset the Name property for few items in the list

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can I not assign a List of concrete types to a List of that concrete's interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772606/why-can-i-not-assign-a-list-of-concrete-types-to-a-list-of-that-concretes-inter)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using .Net 4.0 or greater, you can change your IList(T) to an IEnumerable(T) and it will work. The IList(T) interface's T parameter is not covariant and IEnumerable(T) interface's T parameter is. See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx

for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Incase if i want to return the updated list from my method, should i user IEnumerable<ILeader> as return type and cast it back to List<User> or List<Group> wherever i call this method ?

Comment: @Happy, IEnumerable<T> is readonly, so you cannot add/remove items using this method. However, you can modify the items themselves (e.g. change their Name properties). Consequently, you do not need to return a "resulting list", because the original list is unchanged.

Answer (score 5):

Because `IList<T>` is not covariant, which means there's nothing from stopping `ChangeList` from adding a `Group` to the list of `Users`, which is obviously invalid.

To pass a list of both kinds, convert the list to a `List<ILeader>`:

```
ChangeList(userList.Cast<ILeader>().ToList());
```

However be aware that this doesn't actually *cast* the list, it creates a *new* list where each member is an instance of `ILeader`.  Which means that ChangeList could add a `Group` to the list, meaning you couldn't convert it back to a `List<User>`.

If `ChangeList` doesn't add any members to the list you can just convert it back:

```
var leaderList = userList.Cast<ILeader>().ToList();
ChangeList(leaderList);  
userList = leaderList.Cast<User>().ToList();
```

If `ChangeList` *adds* any items other than `User`s then the conversion will fail.  Your best choice is to take *only* the `User`s from the result:

```
var leaderList = userList.Cast<ILeader>().ToList();
ChangeList(leaderList);  
userList = leaderList.OfType<User>().ToList();  // will ignore anything that's not a `User`
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. i want my changelist method to make changes to the Name property values of some users in the list and return it back. what should be my return type.

Comment: Technically you don't need one since the List is just a reference to the underlying objects, however it would be _better_ to return an `IList<ILeader>` and leave the passed-in list alone.  Most "change" methods don't change in the passed-in reference but return a new instance instead.

Comment: OK. So when calling the method, i should cast it with  `as List<User>;` ?

Comment: No, you can't _cast_ it to a List<User> - you have to convert it using the method above

Answer (score 3):

You should actually rely on generic type constraint on your second method:

```
public void ChangeList<T>(IList<T> leaderList) where T : ILeader
{
  //do some thing           
}
```

Now you can pass both the lists.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, classes are not covarient, which is the feature you're trying to use here.  See [this FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) for more information on that.

> A couple of important rules to remember:
>
> This feature works only for generic interfaces and delegates. If you implement a variant generic interface, the implementing class is still invariant. Classes and structs do not support variance in C# 4.0.
>      So the following doesn’t compile:
>
> ```
> // List<T> implements the covariant interface
> // IEnumerable<out T>. But classes are invariant.
> List<Person> list = new List<Employee>(); // Compiler error here.
> ```

In order to make this work, you need to cast your `User` to an `ILeader`.  You'd do this with `userList.Cast<ILeader>()`.