# Cannot cast List<item> to generic

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a generic property that's meant to represent a list of physical addresses:

```
public T PhysicalAddressList
{
    get => GetPhysicalAddressListValue<T>(_physicalAddressList);
    set => _physicalAddressList = SetPhysicalAddressListValue<T>(value);
}
```

I'm using a field for the `get` and `set`. However, I need to run a few changes on the field throughout the duration of this base class's lifetime. For that reason the field `_physicalAddressList` is explicitly declared as:

```
List<PhysicalAddressDTO> _physicalAddressList;
```

Naturally, this means I'll have to convert it from the generic to the definition (`set`) and back to the generic (`get`) using methods. Now, I've managed to work out the `set` aspect of the property fairly easily.
The `get` is the issue I have. Simply put, I cannot cast a List through to a generic type:

```
private T GetPhysicalAddressListValue<TPhysicalAddress>(List<PhysicalAddressDTO> 
physicalAddressList)
{
    if (physicalAddressList is T)
        return (T)physicalAddressList;
    else
    {
        Type genericType = typeof(T);
        // Code to convert parameter into datatype specified in genericType

        if (convertedPhysicalAddressList is T)
            return (T)convertedPhysicalAddressList; // Cannot convert type 'List<PhysicalAddressDTO>' to 'T'
    }
}
```

I'm confused because ideally, I'd normally get this error at runtime if the two aren't compatible. However, this error appears while coding... after ensuring the type being cast matches the expected generic.

Why can other types can be cast to generics while List's cannot?

Side note: (IEnumerables don't give me this problem. But here, I can't use an IEnumerable because... you know... `T` isn't an `IEnumerable`).

So, any suggestions would be much appreciated. How do I go about this?

Comment: Why your class is generic when you actually work with specific type? You can cast anything to generic type with `(T)(object)value` but it may fail at runtime with `InvalidCastException`

Comment: @JL0PD This class is a base viewmodel that's referenced by a few other classes. In this instance, it's being overloaded with `CompanyPhysicalAddressDTO` but it can also be overloaded by `PersonPhysicalAddressDTO` and `EmployeePhysicalAddressDTO` for instance. However, all these models have in common is the `PhysicalAddressBaseDTO` base class. As a result, I made this viewmodel take in parameters that inherit form `PhysicalVIewModelBase`. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'll try it out now.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), but `IList<T>` is not.

Covariance means that you can do implicit conversion of an array of a more derived type to an array of a less derived type:

```
IEnumerable<String> strings = new List<String>();
IEnumerable<Object> objects = strings;
```

There are many answers why `IList<T>` is not covariant, see for example here: [ICollection<T> not Covariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996626/icollectiont-not-covariant) or here: [Why can I not assign a List of concrete types to a List of that concrete's interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772606/why-can-i-not-assign-a-list-of-concrete-types-to-a-list-of-that-concretes-inter).

Is it possible to avoid converting from one list to another and use list of objects of the base type everywhere? If no, you can use the following construction:

```
physicalAddressList.Cast<PhysicalAddressDTO>().ToList()
```