# Can't add Lazy to List of Lazy with generic supertype

Tags: c#, unity-container, lazy-evaluation

I'm using Unity to resolve dependencies. There's a rather heavy class with some rather heavy dependencies. It kinda looks like this:

```
public interface IPicturesDownloader : IDownloadData { }
public interface IDataDownloader : IDownloadData { }
public interface ITextDownloader : IDownloadData { }

public interface IDownloadData
{
    void Download();
}

public class HeavyClass : IHeavyClass
{
    private readonly List<IDownloadData> _downloaders = new List<IDownloadData>();

    public HeavyClass(
        IPicturesDownloader a,
        IDataDownloader b,
        ITextDownloader c
        /*etc*/)
    {
        _downloaders.Add(a);
        _downloaders.Add(b);
        _downloaders.Add(c);
    }

    public void DownloadEverything()
    {
        foreach (var downloader in _downloaders)
            downloader.Download();
    }
}
```

To spread loading of instantiating the HeavyClass a little, I made the downloaders `Lazy`:

```
public class HeavyLazyClass : IHeavyClass
{
    private readonly List<Lazy<IDownloadData>> _downloaders = new List<Lazy<IDownloadData>>();

    public HeavyLazyClass(
        Lazy<IPicturesDownloader> a,
        Lazy<IDataDownloader> b,
        Lazy<ITextDownloader> c
        /*etc*/)
    {
        _downloaders.Add(a);
        _downloaders.Add(b);
        _downloaders.Add(c);
    }

    public void DownloadEverything()
    {
        foreach (var downloader in _downloaders)
            downloader.Value.Download();
    }
}
```

However, this problem occurs when making everything lazy:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Lazy<My.Namespace.IPicturesDownloader>' to 'System.Lazy<My.Namespace.IDownloadData>'
>
> Argument type 'System.Lazy<My.Namespace.IPicturesDownloader>' is not assignable from 'System.Lazy<My.Namespace.IDownloadData>'

Howevery, one would say: the downloaders implement the required interface, so this should work. Why exactly doesn't it, and what is the best/easiest way to still make this work? It would increase usability tremendously.

I guess I could still fallback to a constructor requiring all IDownloadData's (at least I think Unity can resolve this if configured properly):

```
public HeavyClass(IEnumerable<Lazy<IDownloadData>> dataDownloaders) {}
```

but that would require me to refactor a bunch of classes and unit tests, as well as the unity configuration. So I'd rather omit that and have a more straightforward solution.

I guess [Why can I not assign a List of concrete types to a List of that concrete's interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772606/why-can-i-not-assign-a-list-of-concrete-types-to-a-list-of-that-concretes-inter) is kind of the same question, but I would like some further explaination.

Comment: Are you using Unity (DI container) or Unity3D (game development)?

Comment: How about taking `Func<IPicturesDownloader>` etc in your constructor and create the `Lazy` instances there?

Comment: @sirRufo DI container

Comment: @Servy I don't think this serves as dupe ... `Lazy<Derived>` isn't itself *derived* from `Lazy<Base>`.

Comment: While the underlying problem is the same, the solution is or explanation isn't good on the linked duplicate.

Comment: The underlying problem is that `SomethingSomething<TBase>` is not a base class for `SomethingSomething<TDerived>`.

Comment: It can't be good. A `Lazy` is constructed from a factory function, that's a whole different thing than a container.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I know it isn't derived from it.  The question is asking *why* it isn't.  The dup explains why.

Comment: @FelixPalmen It's not a relevant difference as far as the C# compiler is concerned.  Classes in C# can never be covariant.

Comment: @Servy that's not the entire point ... while you can find *some* explanation on the *general* problem, the actual *solutions* don't match.

Comment: @FelixPalmen The solution is to create a new object of the right generic type (or use a covariant interface instead of a class).  That applies to any type.

Comment: @Servy "Classes can never be covariant" is just another explanation for OP's "*why*" question, but not a solution... for OP's usecase, I'm pretty sure just passing the factory functions to the constructor would be the "best" solution. (and that's what I mean, it's quite different from solutions you'd suggest for the `List<T>` case).

Comment: @FelixPalmen LIke I said right in my comment, there are two solutions, construct new instance of the right type, or use an interface instead of a class, so that it can be covariant.  Those are the only two solutions, they are both described in the duplicate, and they are the only two options for *every* situation, the OP is free to use whichever one they want.